# C# Telegram.bot Исключение (не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS)

Tags: c#, telegram, бот

Пробовал на двух серверах, результат одинаковый..
 До этого всё работало отлично! вечером 06.02 появилась эта проблема..
 Использую dll c репозитория ".NET Client for Telegram Bot API"

```
var me = botClient.GetMeAsync().Result;//Исключение
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, World! I am user {me.Id} and my name is {me.FirstName}.");

botClient.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;
```

Comment: та же проблема. на windows 10 не воспроизводится, на windows server 2012 r2 воспроизводится.

Comment: Полностью текст ошибки предоставьте. Через VPN воспроизводится?

Comment: Ruslan K. - На моих серверах Windows server 2012 r2 выдаёт такие ошибки..
Геннадий П. - Полный текст таков:<Необработанное исключение: System.AggregateException: Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Запрос был прерван: Не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS>

Comment: Может кто-нибудь нашел решение?

Answer (score 1):

Есть основания полагать, что telegram изменил набор поддерживаемых cipher suite на api сервере: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.telegram.org&s=149.154.167.220&hideResults=on

В связи с чем на испытывающих проблемы хостах не осталось ни одного поддерживаемого cipher suite. 
Для OS Windows набор cipher suite можно посмотреть в реестре:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010002`

Comment: Да вероятней... просмотрев у себя реестр на наличие подобных "cipher suite", ни одной не обнаружил, и всё же ума не приложу как можно решить данную проблему...

Answer (score 1):

такая же история что на Win10, что на 2k19
до этого работало отлично

юзаю https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot
и https://github.com/MihaZupan/HttpToSocks5Proxy

нашел ответ тут https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/issues/869#issuecomment-583115520

Telegram now allows only TLS v1.2. You probably need to use this
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

после этого сразу заработало Win10
но на 2k19 не удалось победить(((

Comment: Это ответ или вопрос?

Comment: ответ, на 2k19 тоже победил - снял галку с пункта Использовать TLS 1.0 в свойствах браузера

Comment: На windows 7 потребовалось еще поставить cipher suite с поддержкой TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, в частности KB3042058. После этого все заработало.